# JAPE rule Sentence contains multiple cases

Tags: text, nlp, grammar, logical-operators, gate

How can i check whether a sentence contain combinations? For example consider sentence. 
*John appointed as new CEO for google.* 
I need to write a rule to check whether sentence contains < 'new' + 'Jobtitle' >. 
How can i achieve this. I tried following. I need to check is there 'new' before word .

```
Rule: CustomRules
(
    {
        Sentence contains {Lookup.majorType == "organization"},
        Sentence contains {Lookup.majorType == "jobtitle"},
        Sentence contains {Lookup.majorType == "person_first"}
    }
)
```

Comment: See following question. It alows you to limit a JAPE patern to match within a single sentece only. Then you can select the coreponding sentence using another JAPE. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198611/jape-file-to-find-the-pattern-within-a-sentence

Answer (score 2):

One way to handle this is to revert it. Focus on the sequence you need and then get the covering Sentence:

```
(
  {Token@string == "new"}
  {Lookup.majorType = "jobtitle"}
):newJT
```

You should check this edge when the Sentence starts after "new", like this:

```
new

CEO
```

You can use something like this:

```
{Token ... }
{!Sentence, Lookup.majorType ...}
```

And then get the sentence (if you really need it) in the java RHS:

```
long end = newJTAnnots.lastNode().getOffset();
long start = newJTAnnots.firstNode().getOffset();
AnnotationSet sentences = inputAS.get("Sentence", start, end);
```