# JAPE grammar sentence boundaries in GATE

Tags: nlp, gate, information-extraction

please if I need to specify to check the pattern if it in one sentence or not?

My patterns are:
{person}

{Token}*

{Token.string = "call"}

{Token}*

{person}

to be in one sentence.

how could I do this please using JAPE

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jape file to find the pattern within a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198611/jape-file-to-find-the-pattern-within-a-sentence)

Comment: There is a nice trick using the `Split` annotation for this. See the linked question in my previous comment. See the second answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29208418/1857897